# validateMenuItem to disable specific menu items

Tags: objective-c, macos, validation, nsmenuitem

I an new to macOS XCode Obj-C so bear with me. I am trying to use `validateMenuItem` to disable and enable specific menu items.

I currently have this working to disable and enable *all menu items:

```
BOOL g_bEnableAllMenus = YES;
```

and then I am using the `validateMenuItem`

```
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)item
{
    if( !g_bEnableAllMenus  )
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

To test, I am calling `g_bEnableAllMenus` in `awakeFromNib` and it is disabling all my menu items correctly.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    g_bEnableAllMenus = NO; 
}
```

What I am trying to do now is this scenario:

Instead of `g_bEnableAllMenu`s disabling and enabling ALL menu items when `g_bEnableAllMenus = YES/NO;` is called, I want it to disable all menu items EXCEPT a list of several other menuItems under a menu called TestMenu.

Then I want this list of other menu items under TestMenu separately controlled with a different BOOL: so I can enable and disable this menu item separately and not have it changed by `g_bEnableAllMenus` - only by `g_bEnableTestMenu`.

`BOOL g_bEnableTestMenu = YES;`

There is where I am stuck. I think I have to use some combination of `[item action] == @selector(TestMenuItem:)` in `validateMenuItem` so when `g_bEnableTestMenu == NO` it disables all menu items under my TestMenu (but doesn't touch other menu items).

Then when `g_bEnableAllMenus == NO` it still disables all my menus (as it correctly does now) but excludes my TestMenu.

Comment: Although menu validation is usually done via testing whether something in the responder chain can handle the item's associated action, if you really want to handle menu validation via a global flag, I guess you could switch based on `item.title` (or any other property for that matter). Btw, your if/else snippet could be just `return g_bEnableAllMenus`

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitemvalidation/3005191-validatemenuitem?language=objc for an example.

Comment: If you want to avoid having to test against menu item actions and selectors, you can set the tag field on your menu items to integer values. The tag values of the test menu items could all be in some range for ease of checking. You don't have to set tags of items you aren't interested in (they will have the default tag value of 0).

Comment: Another solution is an outlet to the Test menu and a test if the `menu` of the item is the Test menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more concrete answer based on my comment above.

You can set a tag value on a menu item to avoid having to match by action/selector. If you're creating the menu items in code just set the .tag property directly; in an .xib layout set it on the main properties tab of the menu item:

[image: screenshot of menu properties user-interface]

Then in your validation handler you can just check the range of the tag:

```
func validateUserInterfaceItem(_ item: NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem) -> Bool {
    if item.tag >= 1000 && item.tag <= 1100 {
        // return your test validation logic result
    } else {
        // return your normal validation result
    }
}
```

Of course you could improve this sample by defining constants for your test-menu-item tag range min and max, or with other data structures (e.g. a CaseIterable enum of test-item tag values). You might want to use tags for other groups of commands that share validation logic that isn't readily determined by selectors/responder-chain.